# Eclipse kepler - Disable javascript validation

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, validation

I just installed the new eclipse kepler (eclipse 4.3). It shows me hundreds of errors and warnings from third party javascript libraries.

I tried to disable the javasscript validation completely by unchecking "Enable JavaScript semantic validation" in "Preferences/JavaScript/Validator", but with no effect - Errors and warnings are still shown.

Is there another option to disable them or is this just a bug?

[image]

Can other people confirm this issue or is it just me? :)

**Edit 1:** Lavie Tobey pointed out, i should set all validations to "ignore" -> did not help

[image]

**Edit 2:**
Jim Garrison pointed out, i should disable the builder for the projects -> Actually I don't have a javascript builder in there. Disabled for testing purposes all of them, but did not help:

[image]

Comment: I think http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/setting_the_javascript_build_path.htm should work for you !

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can go Project properties/Javascript/Include Path/source and exclude the third party components.

Comment: I think this i not valid for the new kepler version, is it? I didn't find that option.

Comment: I see it in my kepler eclipse, yet I don't understand what you mean by `third party components` I see `ECMAScript Buildt-In Library` and `JavaScript Web Project support`. are they the third party ones?

Comment: The OP was suffering from errors for third party javascript libraries within his project. He needed to individually exclude them from validation. It's normal to install libraries under a common sub-directory (eg. components), so then it's easy to exclude the whole components tree from validation.

Answer (score 11):

There are two places you have to look.  You have found the first. The second is in each project's *Properties* dialog, accessed by right-clicking on the project in Package Explorer and selecting "Properties".  There, under *Builders* you may find a "Javascript Validation" entry, which you must disable.

You have to do this for every project that contains a Javascript Validation builder.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Open the .project in notepad and remove the javascript validator

Comment: This is not an answer, and should be added as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that in previous versions of Eclipse, the only way to really get these to go away is to enable it and change every case to "Ignore".

Comment: For me this has no effect as well

Comment: have you tried a clean and "validate"?  there is a validate option in the right-click context menu.

Comment: You have to select the errors in the output window and DELETE them. I know this sounds stupid, how can you delete and error without fixing it? Once you delete them then you can rerun the build and they will be gone. Until then Eclipse caches them and will not remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch off (and configure) validation in Preferences/Validation or (for each project) Properties/Validation. However, this doesn't seem to force a cleanup of the messages.

Answer (score 0):

Like it was said : be sure to go to PROJECT properties (right click on project, properties), and not Workspace (Eclipse/preference). 
I searched like 20 min before hitting myself ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by choosing a PHP profile for my javascript instead. 
Maybe you don't get the same functionality but for me this profile is just fine. Crashes, hangings & frustration went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for XML Validation. I deactivated the validators globally and in the projects itself, nothing worked for me. There wasn't even the slightest hint that anything changed. I even uninstalled XML Editor and Validation Plugins without any effect.

In the end the problem was solved in copy-pasting the XML files with a validation error, deleting the old files and renaming the copies files to the original ones. Somehow Eclipse did not re-validate the old files, but the new ones were okay.